# grab location header for both 'Location:' and 'location:'

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

How to make a pregmatch match both `'location: '` and `'Location: '`?

```
preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $curl, $result)
```

Comment: if you follow your regex with `i` it becomes case insensitive. i.e.: `#Location: (.*)#i`

Answer (score 0):

Just make the regex case insensitive:

```
preg_match('#Location: (.*)#i', $curl, $result)
//                   here __^
```